# Different log files for same project with different main started

Tags: java, logback

I have a project with different entry points (classes with `main()`). I need to start two of them simultaneously with different `main()`. Logging parameters are defined through `logback.xml`. I need both of instances of my project writes to two different files. How to edit `logback.xml` (or maybe there are other ways) to obtain this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the way to solve problem in intelliJ Idea - fill 'VM options'
 field with `-Dlogging.config=<your_logback_file_name>.xml`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 logback.xml files with the different filenames.
Make sure your first java program (main() 1) class path points to the first logback, the second program to the second logback.xml

Comment: Thank you! Do you mind to explain how to set logback through classpath?

Comment: You're probably better with adding this to your command line: -Dlogback.configurationFile=/path/to/customised/logback.xml

So, run

    java -Dlogback.configurationFile=/path/to/customised/logback1.xml com.mypackage.MyMain1

and 

    java -Dlogback.configurationFile=/path/to/customised/logback2.xml com.mypackage.MyMain2

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot make it work. My greatest achivement with the suggested way - creating file I like write log to. However, it empty.